# Problema com @keyframes CSS

Tags: css3, keyframes

Estou fazendo uma animação com CSS mas o efeito fica correto apenas na primeira palavra do texto e o resto não. Alguém saberia o motivo disto ocorrer?

```css
h3{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: consolas;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: transparent;
}

h3:before{
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: type 10s steps(27) infinite;
  color: #000;
}

@keyframes type{
  0%{
    width: 0;
  }
  50%{
    width: 100%;
  }
  100%{
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 data-text="Efeito CSS - Escrever Texto">
  Efeito CSS - Escrever Texto
</h3>
```

Comment: Porque, provavelmente, como você está alterando a largura do elemento, o texto quebra em várias linhas, só aparecendo o texto na mesma linha quando o elemento possui largura suficiente para isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O que estou achando estranho é que a primeira palavra fica com o efeito certo!

Comment: Porque o navegador quebra a palavra no meio se o elemento é menor que a palavra. Tente trabalhar com a propriedade `word-wrap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É como o @AndersonCarlosWoss comentou. Os espaços estão quebrando o texto em linhas porque o elemento não possui largura suficiente para exibir o restante do texto na mesma linha à medida que a largura do elemento é alterada, e o `overflow: hidden` esconde as linhas de baixo. Quando o elemento possui uma largura que caiba uma palavra após um espaço, a palavra aparece de uma vez.

O efeito funciona na primeira palavra porque ela está no início da linha.

Se colocares um `white-space: nowrap;` no `h3` para evitar a quebra de linha verás que o efeito funciona corretamente:

```css
h3{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: consolas;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h3:before{
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: type 10s steps(27) infinite;
  color: #000;
}

@keyframes type{
  0%{
    width: 0;
  }
  50%{
    width: 100%;
  }
  100%{
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 data-text="Efeito CSS - Escrever Texto">
  Efeito CSS - Escrever Texto
</h3>
```

Comment: Pô era isto mesmo sam. Valeu man!!

Answer (score 4):

Uma alternativa à resposta do Sam, é usar a propriedade CSS [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) com o valor `break-all`.

```css
h3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: consolas;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: transparent;
}

h3:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: type 10s steps(27) infinite;
  color: #000;
  word-break: break-all;  /* <--- */
}

@keyframes type {
  0%   { width: 0; }
  50%  { width: 100%; }
  100% { width: 0; }
}
```

```html
<h3 data-text="Efeito CSS - Escrever Texto">
  Efeito CSS - Escrever Texto
</h3>
```

Comment: Boa Fernando, aprendendo mais uma aqui!